# Custom audio effect in just_audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I want to create a custom audio effect for my application but I don't know to do this with limited public interface of AudioEffect class.

```
    abstract class AudioEffect {
      bool get enabled;
      Stream<bool> get enabledStream;
      Future<void> setEnabled(bool enabled);
    }
```

Could you give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in just_audio for custom audio effects, `AudioEffect` represents only the available audio effects provided by the operating system.

Comment: On android platform I found more audio effects: AcousticEchoCanceler
AutomaticGainControl
BassBoost
DynamicsProcessing EnvironmentalReverb Equalizer
HapticGenerator
LoudnessEnhancer NoiseSuppressor PresetReverb
Virtualizer

Do you have plans to support them in just_audio?

Comment: I don't personally plan for all features, but they are implemented as requested or contributed. People can either submit a feature request or contribute a pull request.